# ¿Cómo utilizar el operador NOT IN (<>) en un GROUP_CONCAT con fechas?

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin, mariadb

Tengo la tabla **calendario** con todas las fechas del mes de diciembre del 2021 (sólo ejemplificaré algunas fechas dentro de la tabla, pero se sobreentiende que en realidad contiene todos los días de dicho mes):

| id | fecha |
| --- | --- |
| 01 | 2021-12-01 |
| 02 | 2021-12-02 |
| 03 | 2021-12-03 |
| 04 | 2021-12-04 |
| 05 | 2021-12-05 |

Tengo la tabla **usuarios**:

| id | nombre | no_empleado |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 01 | Andrea | 101 |
| 02 | María | 102 |

Tengo la tabla **asistencias**

| id | fecha | no_empleado |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 01 | 2021-12-03 | 101 |
| 02 | 2021-12-04 | 101 |
| 03 | 2021-12-03 | 102 |
| 04 | 2021-12-04 | 102 |
| 05 | 2021-12-05 | 101 |
| 06 | 2021-12-06 | 102 |

Trabajé en una consulta para desplegar el número de empleado, su nombre, los días en los que asistió y los días en los que faltó:

```
SELECT u.no_empleado, 
       u.nombre, 
       a.fecha AS asistencias,
       c.fecha as faltas FROM usuarios u 
JOIN (SELECT no_empleado, 
      GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT EXTRACT(DAY FROM fecha)) AS fecha FROM asistencias 
      WHERE fecha BETWEEN '2021-12-01' AND '2021-12-31' 
      GROUP BY no_empleado) a ON a.no_empleado = u.no_empleado 
LEFT JOIN (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT EXTRACT(DAY FROM fecha)) AS fecha FROM calendario 
           WHERE fecha BETWEEN '2021-12-01' AND '2021-12-31') c ON c.fecha <> a.fecha
```

Con la consulta anterior, obtengo esto:

| no_empleado | nombre | asistencias | faltas |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 101 | Andrea | 3,4,5 | 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10... |
| 102 | María | 3,4,6 | 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10... |

En la columna de asistencias obtengo los días del mes de diciembre en los que tuvo asistencias cada empleado, y en las faltas debería obtener exclusivamente los días en los que hubo faltas, pero se despliegan todos los días del mes de diciembre.

Estoy casi seguro de que el problema está en cómo evalúo que los números de los días desplegados en la columna **asistencias** no se desplieguen en la columna **faltas**. Específicamente en esta parte considero que está mal mi evaluación:

```
ON c.fecha <> a.fecha
```

Tengo la impresión de que al estar trabajando con `GROUP_CONCAT`, debería evaluar de distinta forma las fechas. ¿Cómo podría adaptar mi consulta para obtener lo siguiente?

| no_empleado | nombre | asistencias | faltas |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 101 | Andrea | 3,4,5 | 1,2,3,6,7,8,9,10... |
| 102 | María | 3,4,6 | 1,2,5,7,8,9,10... |

La consulta en cuestión no puede ser adaptada a utilizar CTE dada a la versión de MariaDB que estoy utilizando. Estoy trabajando en phpMyAdmin.

Answer (score 0):

A partir del producto cartesiano entre usuarios y el calendario agrupa por usuario y evalúa la posible (in)existencia `LEFT JOIN` de la asistencia, es decir, si la fecha es nula en asistencias cuenta como inasistencia:

```
SELECT u.no_empleado
     , u.nombre
     , group_concat( day(a.fecha) 
                     order by c.fecha
                   ) asistencias
     , group_concat( if(a.fecha is null, day(c.fecha), null) 
                     order by c.fecha
                   ) faltas
  FROM usuarios u
    JOIN calendario c
    LEFT JOIN asistencias a
      ON    a.no_empleado = u.no_empleado
        AND a.fecha = c.fecha
  WHERE c.fecha between '2021-12-01' and '2021-12-31'
  GROUP BY u.id
         , u.no_empleado
```